# Charting live data with .NET C#

Tags: c#, .net, charts

I am looking for a way to chart data using C# .NET. I have a SQLite file containing the data I wish to chart, but the data is updated every 15 seconds and I would like to have the ability to "animate" or live update the data at a specified interval.

I was using ASP.NET charting controls but found it to slow down as more data is added. When I was using this method, I simply placed an auto refresh on the page and regenerated the graph each time.

I am open to using any .NET technology available to present this data (i.e. Silverlight, WPF, .NET, etc.).

I also would like to avoid using any third party PAID software, FOSS .NET solutions are fine.

Does anyone know how to present the data and generate the graph so the chart only renders additions instead of rebuilding the entire graph each time the "page" is reloaded?

Thanks!

Comment: what were you using with asp.net ? Did you try flot : http://code.google.com/p/flot/ http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/realtime.html ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**WPF** and **Silverlight** both support [data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx).  If the data being monitored supports [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) and, for collections, [INotifyCollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx), then some behind-the-scenes [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) technology gets hooked up and you can get have portions of your GUI respond to very precise changes in your data rather than having to refresh everything.  This technology is probably exactly what you are looking for, but may take a little legwork on your part if you aren't familiar with the technology, which is one of the backbones of WPF and of Silverlight.

Fortunately, getting started is not hard, and is a great investment in knowledge.  Perhaps start with one of the many [free databinding tutorials](http://www.wpftutorial.net/DataBindingOverview.html), or I recommend one of the web certification video courses, such as those offered by [PluralSight](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/courses/tableofcontents?courseName=wpf-fundamentals).

Answer (score 0):

Well i would suggest some Commercial Control's which works fine and are fast enough .
http://devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/Charting/
http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/Chart/

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a couple of systems that streamed high frequency financial data to client browsers. They used:

- Silverlight for the ui.
- Silverlight toolkit for the charting components.
- a .net server service to collate and push the updates to the clients.
- .net sockets used as the transport mechanism. In your case, the updates are relatively infrequent, so you could use  Duplex WCF.

I would suggest looking at tutorials on :

- [Silverlight MVVM](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/advanced-techniques/the-mvvm-pattern/using-the-mvvm-pattern-in-silverlight-applications)
- .[Pushing data to Silverlight apps using WCF](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2008/06/19/pushing-data-to-a-silverlight-client-with-a-wcf-duplex-service-part-ii.aspx)
- .[Silverlight toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/)
- optionally [.net sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296248%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

In using Silverlight and pushing updates to the client this way, only the new/ updated data changes, therefore only this data is rendered and there are no page reloads.